# How to easily add start page to existing c# wpf app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF that has a `MainWindow` that is opened at startup. `MainWindow` has a Menu and Dockpanel that has a bunch of things:

```
<Window x:Class="test.Testing"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Closing="Window_Closing"
        Height="450" Width="800">

    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </Menu>
        <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" >
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I am trying to find the easiest way to add a start page to this like this:

```
<Window x:Class="test.Testing"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Closing="Window_Closing"
        Height="450" Width="800">

 <Page Name="StartPage">
 </Page>

  <Page Name="TestPage">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </Menu>
        <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" >
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
 </Page>


</Window>
```

However, when I do that, it complains that a Page has 'Content' set more than once (Menu,DockPanel). If I simply add another outer Dockpanel, Window complains that its content is being set more than once. I am trying to get something such that there is no overlap of content (`Startpage` fills up the whole window, OR `TestPage` fills up the whole window).

Comment: Should the "start page" replace the `DockPanel`?

Answer (score 0):

You used Page tag twice. window accepts only one child.
you should remove one of page elements or wrap them in another element like grid or stack or something else like:

```
<Grid>
 <Page Name="StartPage"> </Page>
 <Page Name="TestPage">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </Menu>
        <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" >
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
 </Page>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The effect I want is to have one or the other *pages* show. Wouldn't this split it up into two rows or columns?

Comment: it depends on the container you want to use and how use it. like if you define rows or column in grid control it will be shown that way but if you want them to replace each other, you can display one of them by hiding the other one.

Comment: but in general this approach (using two page element in a window) is not a good practice . you should consider navigating between pages in wpf like pages of a website : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBh0weP1bmo